# php generated javascript files don't excecute

Tags: php, javascript, execution, generated

I'm trying to create a module for Drupal to clean up some of the inline javascript that's put on every page. The problem is, the files that I am generating are not being executed by the browser when they are included with the `<script>` tag. Here's a basic overview of what I'm doing:

Module specific code (this code is executed whenever mysite.com/jqsc/MD5_HASH_GOES_HERE is visited, passing the MD5 sum as the first parameter):

```
function jquery_settings_cache_get($hash) {
    header('content-type: application/x-javascript');

    if (file_exists(dirname(__FILE__) . "/cache/{$hash}")) {
        exit(file_get_contents(dirname(__FILE__) . "/cache/{$hash}"));
    }
    else {
        watchdog('jqsc', "missing file {$hash}", null, WATCHDOG_ERROR);
        exit("// JQuery Settings Cache error -- missing file {$hash}");
    }
}
```

Current HASH.js file (this is linked from a script tag in the HTML template):

```
alert('it works!');
```

Current HTML output (some irrelevant code has been removed):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <base href="http://example.com/sites/all/themes/mytheme/" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/default/files/js/js_80a1e7d5d876d5176617603a4bbe39fe.js"></script> <!-- This file loads fine -->
  <script type="text/javascipt" src="/jqsc/deaa654d439f644fd473db0af4d993fe.js"></script> <!-- This file never loads -->
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Navigating to mysite.com/jqsc/HASH.js brings up the file with the correct contents (just an alert() for the moment). There are no comments to be unclosed, missing function declarations, or anything else a google search for "external javascript not executing" yielded. Firebug shows that the 2nd file is never executed (it never stops at a breakpoint set within the file). Live HTTP Headers shows that the correct content-type has been set (I've tried application/javascript, application/x-javascript, and text/javascript all with the same effect. Putting file #2 before file #1 has no effect. Changing the transport-encoding has no effect. Changing the charset has no effect. Changing the `<script>` tag to use `language=javascript` with or without `type="text/javascript"` or omitting all `<script>` tag properties except `src` has no effect.

I'm officially stuck. Anything you can think of to dig me out of this hole is greatly appreciated.

Comment: your 2d script tag has a type="text/javascipt" which is not text/javascript, and as such won't run.

Comment: What a stupid mistake I made! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You might be calling the wrong file here:

```
<script type="text/javascipt" src="/jqsc/deaa654d439f644fd473db0af4d993fe.js"></script>
```

on second thought. Disregard that because of utter failishness.

The "there is a typo in your javascript" comment above is much closer to the truth probably ;)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jqsc/deaa654d439f644fd473db0af4d993fe.js"></script>
```

:D